# How would A* search a graph?

Tags: algorithm, a-star, heuristics

[image]
    An A* search will start at node S and continue to node G. At node S, the open 
    list will contain A and B with values 7 and 6 respectively. Create a table 
    showing the open list for each node that is visited as the A* algorithm 
    progresses.

Can anyone explain to me how A* will search this.

```
open list = [S]; closed list = []
open list = [A,B]; closed list = [S]
whats next?
```

Comment: It isn't homework.........

Comment: What do you think is next? And why (try to explain why you think the next step will be whatever you think it will be)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**A* is a best-first algorithm**, which means that it explores a graph by expanding **the most promising node** chosen according to a specified rule. In this case, the rule is that the most promising node is the one with **the smallest  f-value**, where **f(n) = g(n) + h(n)**, i.e. the sum of what was already walked (g-value) plus what our heuristic "promise" us that is the remaining of the path (h-value) is minimum.

Thus, let me write the open list in order, since generally the open list for A* is a priority queue:

```
it 0: open list = [S]; closed list = []

it 1: in this iteration we will have closed list = [S] and a PQ of open nodes with,
open list = 
| (B, 6) | (g = 3 + h = 3)
| (A, 7) | (g = 2 + h = 5)
```

after this, B is the most promising path (6 < 7) so this node will be put in the closed list,

```
it 2: closed list = [S,B];
open list = 
| (A, 7) | (g = 2 + h = 5)
| (D, 10) | (g = 6 + h = 4)
| (C, 11) | (g = 8 + h = 3)
```

and again the algorithm chooses to expand the node with lower f-value (A),

```
it 3: closed list = [S,B,A];
open list = 
| (C, 9) | (g = 6 + h = 3) <-- new path found with lower g-value, we update the node
| (D, 10) | (g = 6 + h = 4)
```

after updating the cost of the path found to C (S->A->C) which has a lower cost than (S->B->C), that node becomes the most promising for A*,

```
it 4: closed list = [S,B,A,C];
open list =
| (F, 9) | (g = 8 + h = 1)
| (D, 10) | (g = 6 + h = 4)
| (E, 13) | (g = 10 + h = 3)
```

F is now the most promising and it is expanded,

```
it 5: closed list = [S,B,A,C,F];
open list = 
| (G, 9) | (g = 9 + h = 0)
| (D, 10) | (g = 6 + h = 4)
| (E, 13) | (g = 10 + h = 3)
```

we have already added the goal node to the open list, **but this doesn't mean the algorithm finishes**, since there might be (not in this problem) still other paths shorter than the one already found (S->A->C->F->G). **The algorithm will finish when a goal node is expanded.** In the next iteration we expand again the most promising node.

```
it 6: we expand the goal node G.
```

The algorithm finishes and returns the path S->A->C->F->G with cost 9.

---

Please pay attention that **your heuristic function is consistent**, which means that once a node is expanded (or put to the closed list) by the A* search algorithm, the cost by which it was reached is the lowest possible (assuming no negative cost cycles). This also means that **the heuristic is admissible** and **A* guarantees the solution found is the shortest possible path** from S to G. Even more, **when A* uses a consistent heuristic it is an optimal algorithm**, i.e. there is no other algorithm that with the same heuristic information can expand less nodes and still guarantee to find the shortest path.